# node javascript string comparison not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand why my comparison is not working , when the console output displays the correct value ...

```
console.log(chalk.yellow('PROCESS.ENV.NODE_ENV: ', process.env.NODE_ENV))

if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
  console.log('true');
} else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

the console output:

```
PROCESS.ENV.NODE_ENV:  "development"
false
```

crazy.. but d I don't see why is failing ....
feedback welcome, or donate for new glasses ...

Comment: if that's the actual output of the console log, there are quotes around `"development"`, which makes it `"\"development"\"` which is not equals to `"development"`

Comment: are those quotes part of the string?

Comment: They are. I just tested it with chalk, just not to look too dumb once more.

Comment: can you show, how you are executing your file?

Comment: you're right ! forgot to check it...  NODE_ENV: '"development"',

Comment: As the other commenters have mentioned there are literal double quotes in that string. Use this `.replace(/"/g, '')`  to replace them.

Comment: also, you should compare using === instead of ==

Comment: @Radar155 please do explain *why*, and what the difference is

Comment: @TimothyGroote https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript